# Introduction about session and a cookie?

Tags: session, cookies

Give brief introduction to what is session?

and

what is cookie?

Can anyone explain what is the difference between session and cookie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are session and cookies the same thing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787265/are-session-and-cookies-the-same-thing)

Comment: if you had searched ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=difference+between+session+and+cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference is, Sessions are in server-side, Cookies are in client-side
Session ends when user close the browser.   Cookie ends depends on the life time set for it.